# file api to create,read,write through intel xdk

Tags: local-storage, intel-xdk

I am creating a mobile app using `intelxdk`,its like a offline app. I wanna store some data in local system through file api(currently storing in local storage, wanna move to file).

**my code:**

```
  document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        readDataUrl(file);
        readAsText(file);
    }

    function readDataUrl(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as data URL");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as text");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function fail(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }
```

**its giving error code 1.**

Need any other suggestions to save data in file instead of local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example of File API usage in IntelXDK:
https://github.com/krisrak/html5-cordova-samples/tree/master/file

You cannot test in emulator, you have build the app and install on device to test File API.

Comment: your example were working and where can i find the file in my mobile directory.